# How to insert custom string in the result of Linux paste command

Tags: linux, shell, paste

I know the Linux command `paste` can be used to combine two lines in two files. My question is how can I add some other string inside them?

For example, I have 2 files:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat c1
aaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbb
[root@localhost ~]# cat c2
11111111
222222222222
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# paste c1 c2
aaaa    11111111
bbbbbbbbbbbbb   222222222222
[root@localhost ~]#
```

How can I insert text between them, for example, how can I get the following result?

```
var aaaa = some_function(11111111);
var bbbbbbbbbbbbb = some_function(222222222222);
```

Can this be implemented by the ***paste*** command? Thanks.

Comment: You can use a `sed` command on the output of `paste`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a way to do this with `paste`, but it can certainly be done easily with `awk`:

```
paste c1 c2 | awk '{ printf("var %s = some_function(%s);\n", $1, $2); }'
```

Answer (score 2):

process your file through with a separate command and pipe it to the `paste` command

```
your_command c1 | paste c1 - c2
```